# Sending data using AJAX and redirect in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending data when a button is clicked using AJAX. When data is sent to PHP server(Codeigniter framework), it will do some processing on server and retrieve the data from the database and should then redirect to another page with the retrieved data,

Below is the AJAX call,

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: baseURL + "admin/reports/",
 data: {rep_id:report_ids},
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
}
});
```

Below is the PHP processing,

```
$data = $this->admin_model->fetch_date($this->input->post('rep_id', TRUE));
$this->load->view('user/report', $data);
```

If I use the above PHP code, then it will not redirect to another page, but it will try to send the complete view file as AJAX an response(which I am able to see in the browser via inspect),

So my question is, how can I perform a redirect with my complete `$data` array?

Comment: you want to send data back to you page for rendering?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to redirect to your desired view with id in parameter like

```
$para array( 'id'=>$report_ids);
redirect('admin/reports/'.$para);
```

after redirecting to URL then you should have send the ajax call

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: baseURL + "admin/reports/",
 data: {rep_id:report_ids}, // Here you have to get your id from url with jQuery
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
}
});
```

Now you have your complete data on the redirected page.

You can append it to any div with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...In php use have to use `json_encode()` for sending back response as below..

```
$data = $this->admin_model->fetch_date($this->input->post('rep_id', TRUE));//Fetch your data in array format

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your AJAX..

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: baseURL + "admin/reports/",
 data: {rep_id:report_ids}, // Here you have to get your id from url with jQuery
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 var objData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);//objData is in object format...
 //try  console.log(objData);
 window.location.href('user/report?name='+objData.name);//name is attribute of your object
}
});
```

Comment: i don't want data to be return on this page, but need to go to another page

Comment: I think you can not redirect to another page..from php code...use `location.href` on js to redirection.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati `can not redirect to another page..from php code` that's absolutelly untrue...all you have to use is header("Location:xxxx")

Comment: @ Nishanth Matha i think not possible to redirect from php on ajax call...so page is redirected from js.

Comment: @HikmatSijapati no matter what call it is once the script encounters `header` it will redirect

Comment: yes ...but if js fetched from external file then problem will occurrs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using ajax in a wrong way!

When a php proccess is called via ajax, redirecting in php is not meaningful any more. After you retrieve data via ajax you should do redirect in jQuery.

Firstly just echo json data in php :

```
$data = $this->admin_model->fetch_date($this->input->post('rep_id', TRUE));//Fetch your data in array format

echo json_encode($data);
```

then redirect when data retrieved :

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: baseURL + "admin/reports/",
 data: {rep_id:report_ids}, // Here you have to get your id from url with jQuery
 type: "POST",
 success:function(data){
 // do not pars json!
 window.location = '/user/report?data=' + objData; // sending json as a string in query string
}
});
```

now in `/user/report` view  pars json with jQuery for usage

**UPDATE:**

I think you dont need ajax at all! Ajax is to help us not having redirection!

Try this :

```
<a href="/admin/report"> GET REPORT! </a>
```

and in your php :

```
$data = $this->admin_model->fetch_date($this->input->post('rep_id', TRUE));
$this->load->view('user/report', $data);
```

Comment: I tried same and was using in same way, but my $data is complete array, how can i pass it in windw.location as array?

Comment: @rjcode but I think this way is not efficient!  try to redirect to `user/report`  by clicking first and then send ajax request from there

Comment: yes i realised no need to AJAX, i did some changes in JS and in PHP and get required results, updating in my answer now, thanks..

Comment: you mean updating your question!  is problem solved!?

Answer (score 0):

If using code igniter you could try using `flashdata` (temporary session) and `header`

Try:

```
$data = $this->admin_model->fetch_date($this->input->post('rep_id', TRUE));
$this->session->set_flashdata('tempValue', '$data');
header("Location: http://yousite/user/report");
exit;
```

Then in your `user/report` to get the data use :

```
$this->session->flashdata('tempValue');
```

**BUT** I think you don't need ajax at all, in the first place,  if you use standard `html` and `POST` the data to your `admin/reports/` using the plain `web form` with `action="admin/reports/"`. In this case your `PHP` can exactly be the same as in OP

Answer (score 0):

I removed AJAX and did simple redirect in JS,

```
window.location = baseURL + 'admin/reports/test/' + rep_id;
```

Then PHP code, use `rep_id` as function variable and did processing and loaded View page,

```
public function test($in)
{
  $data['test'] = $this->admin_model->fetch_insight($in);
  $this->load->view('user/report', $data);
}
```